# What exactly does context do in K?

Tags: kframework

The use of context is briefly mentioned in the [K tutorial](https://github.com/kframework/k/tree/master/k-distribution/tutorial/1_k/4_imp%2B%2B/lesson_4) as a way to customize the order evaluation. But I'm also seeing other context statements that contain rewrite arrows in them, like [this one](https://github.com/kframework/k/blob/master/k-distribution/tutorial/2_languages/1_simple/1_untyped/simple-untyped.k#L543) in the untyped simple language.

```
context ++(HOLE => lvalue(HOLE))
rule <k> ++loc(L) => I +Int 1 ...</k>
     <store>... L |-> (I => I +Int 1) ...</store>  [increment]
```

Could someone explain how exactly context work in K? In particular, I'm interested in:

- Is there a more general usage of `context` in K than just stating the order of evaluation?
- How does the order in which `context` statements are declared affect the semantics?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More detailed information about context declarations in K can be found in K's documentation [here](https://github.com/kframework/k/blob/master/pending-documentation.md#evaluation-strategy). In particular, contexts with rewrite arrows mean that heating and cooling will wrap the term to be heated or cooled in a particular symbol. In your example, that symbol is `lvalue`.

To answer your questions specifically:

- Context declarations, like strictness attributes, are primarily used in order to specify the evaluation strategy. While in theory they can be used for other things, in practice this rarely happens. That said, evaluation strategies can be complex, which is part of why K has so many different features relating to evaluation strategy. In the example you mentioned, we use rewrites in a context declaration in order to provide a separate set of rules for evaluating lvalues (ie, to avoid actually evaluating all the way to a value, and only evaluate to a location).
- K's sentences are unordered. Within a single module, you can reorder any of its sentences (except import statements, which must appear first) and there will not be an effect on the intended semantics (although backends may result in slightly different behavior for concrete execution if your semantics is nondeterministic). This includes context declarations.

Comment: I see. Thank you Dwight!